# Java child class equal to parent via parent's attributes alone

Tags: java, inheritance, equals

I have the following parent class:

```
public class Coordinates {
    private int xCoordinate;
    private int yCoordinate;

    public Coordinates(int xCoordinate, int yCoordinate) {
        this(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, 10, false);
    }

    public Coordinates(int xCoordinate, int yCoordinate, int max) {
        this(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, max, false);
    }

    public Coordinates(int xCoordinate, int yCoordinate, int max, boolean allowedZero) {
        if (allowedZero) {
            if ((xCoordinate >= 0 && yCoordinate >= 0) && (xCoordinate <= max && yCoordinate <= max)) {
                this.xCoordinate = xCoordinate;
                this.yCoordinate = yCoordinate;
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Either X or Y has set to value <= 0, or > %d", max));
            }
        } else {
            if ((xCoordinate > 0 && yCoordinate > 0) && (xCoordinate <= max && yCoordinate <= max)) {
                this.xCoordinate = xCoordinate;
                this.yCoordinate = yCoordinate;
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Either X or Y has set to value <= 0, or > %d", max));
            }
        }

    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Coordinates that = (Coordinates) o;
        return xCoordinate == that.xCoordinate &&
                yCoordinate == that.yCoordinate;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(xCoordinate, yCoordinate);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Coordinates (%d, %d)", xCoordinate, yCoordinate);
    }
}
```

I have also created the following child class:

```
public class Segment extends Coordinates {
    private boolean isDestroyed;

    public Segment(int xCoordinate, int yCoordinate) {
        super(xCoordinate, yCoordinate);
        this.isDestroyed = false;
    }

    public Segment(int xCoordinate, int yCoordinate, int max) {
        super(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, max);
        this.isDestroyed = false;
    }

    public Segment(int xCoordinate, int yCoordinate, int max, boolean allowedZero) {
        super(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, max, allowedZero);
        this.isDestroyed = false;
    }

    public boolean isDestroyed() {
        return isDestroyed;
    }

    public void setDestroyed(boolean destroyed) {
        isDestroyed = destroyed;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return super.equals(o);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return super.hashCode();
    }
}
```

Since "Segment" is just a "Coordinates" class with one new field, I would like them to be directly comparable to each other, via "Coordinates" class' X and Y fields alone. However, at the moment I am failing junit4 test case, where I compare the following:

```
    @Test
    public void testSegmentToCoordinateComparison() {
        // Given
        Segment segment = new Segment(1, 1);

        // When
        Coordinates coordinates = new Coordinates(1, 1);

        // Then
        Assert.assertEquals(coordinates, segment);
    }
```

Error printed is as follows:

```
expected: package.Coordinates<Coordinates (1, 1)> but was: package.Segment<Coordinates (1, 1)>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your equals method is

```java
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Coordinates that = (Coordinates) o;
        return xCoordinate == that.xCoordinate &&
                yCoordinate == that.yCoordinate;
    }
```

The main offender here is `getClass() != o.getClass()`, since getClass in this case is `Coordinates` and o.getClass is `Segment`. You don't want to match up the classes, you just want all subclasses of Coordinates to use Coordinates for comparison. So try using instanceof Coordinates instead, something like,

```java
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        /* What instanceof is telling us here is that a cast to Coordinates
         * won't generate an error because it's the same class, or a subclass
         * or implementing class of Coordinates.
         */
        if (o instanceof Coordinates) { //evaluates to false if o is null 
            Coordinates that = (Coordinates) o;
            return xCoordinate == that.xCoordinate &&
                    yCoordinate == that.yCoordinate;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

You get bonus points for overriding hashCode to reflect your intent for equality comparison, that really helped me understand your question :)

Comment: Last thoughts: consider adding a getter for xCoordinate and yCoordinate and using the getters instead of direct field access.

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked flawlessly. I sometimes tend to read over the auto-generated equals() and hashcode() method implementations. My bad, and Intellij`s for being so damn convenient ;)